# Ошибка не выводится в fail (VK API)

Tags: javascript, ajax, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Посылаю запрос серверу из веб-странички так:

```js
    function zapros(id, offset, count) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get",
            data: {
                owner_id: id,
                extended: 0,
                v: "5.44",
                offset: offset || 0,
                count: count || 100
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) { alert("ответ получен"); },
            fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("ошибка: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
 }
```

Если `id` неактуален (ну удалили его, или ещё что-то), то сервер высылает:

> {"error": {"error_code":18,"error_msg":"User was deleted or
>   banned","request_params":....

Ну это типа ошибка такая, но почему она не выводится в fail? Я ж её правильно указываю так?

```js
    fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("ошибка: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown); 
          }
```

Но не выводит. Что не так? Что ему надо?

Comment: Это ошибка приходит в виде ответа..то есть в `success`.... то есть по факту запрос выполнился, просто данные не подходят....... а  fail  сработает  если с самим запросом что-то не так технически

Comment: Нет, она в Хроме видна, в Нетворке

Comment: Кто "Она" ? ...........напишите `success: function (data) { 
      if (data && data.error) {
       alert("ответ получен: error " + data.error.error_code + ': ' + data.error.error_msg);        
      }
     },`  может так яснее станет

Comment: Вообще в целом для ошибок используется `errror`, а чтобы использовать `fail` надо писать немного по-другому...ибо это `jqXHR-объект`......... но так или иначе именно ответы от ВК в виде `{"error": {"error_code":18,"error_msg":"User was deleted or banned","` попадают в `success`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Если *АПИ* контакта функционирует исправно, то все ответы от него приходят в `success`, в том числе и `{"error": {"error_code":18,"error_msg`, так как это является ответом на попытку выполнения какого-либо метода, а не ошибкой самого сервера. Также взглянув во вкладку `Network` инструментов разработчика мы увидим статус ***200***. Т.е. `OK` - успешно всё. Что и требовалось доказать..

Углубляемся.....

Например, если мы взглянем [вот сюда](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=1) - ответ есть, как и ожидается..... Если взглянуть на тот же запрос удаленного пользователя [тык в меня](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=72404236) то мы все также видим ответ от *АПИ*, результатом которого просто просто получается сообщение о том, почему не получилось что-то выбрать.

Вот если бы вместо этого ответа страница была бы к примеру не найдена, например:  http://yandex.ru/404 (not found) или вообще **500 (internal server error)** -  это можно также посмотреть в `Network`'е, то тогда такие ошибки в запросах уже можно было ловить в функции `error` данного аякс запроса...

Простейшая эмуляция:
Аякс запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someServerUrl.php",   
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {  
        if (data && data.error) {
            alert("ответ получен: error " + data.error.error_code + ': ' + data.error.error_msg); 
            console.log(data.error.error_code + ': ' + data.error.error_msg);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ошибка: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Ответ сервера (на php):

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
```

в результате в `error` отобразится: `ошибка: error Internal Server Booboo{"message":"ERROR","code":1337}`

---

Это же самое правило (на счет ошибок) касается и `fail`....

Вкратце по поводу `fail`:

Метод `$.ajax()` возвращает `jqXHR`-объект. `jqXHR`-объект является расширением `XMLHttpRequest`-объекта браузера

`jqXHR`-объекты возвращаемые методом `$.ajax()` реализуют интерфейс `Promise`, предоставляя им все свойства, методы и поведение `Promise`. Эти методы принимают одну или несколько функций в качестве аргументов, вызываемые методом `$.ajax()`, когда запрос завершается. Такой подход позволяет назначить несколько обработчиков на один AJAX-запрос и даже после отправки запроса.

Одним из этих методом и является `jqXHR.fail()`

Как пользоваться:

```
var jqxhr;

jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: "get.php", 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {  
        if (data && data.error) {
            alert("ответ получен: error " + data.error.error_code + ': ' + data.error.error_msg); 
            console.log(data.error.error_code + ': ' + data.error.error_msg);
        }
    }
});

jqxhr.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("Объект deferred принял состояние rejected." +"Это значит, что задача была выполнена с ошибкой.");
    console.log("ошибка: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

на сервере также эмулируем ошибку как в прошлый раз:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
```

В результате в `fail` откроется алерт `Объект deferred принял состояние rejected." +"Это значит, что задача была выполнена с ошибкой.` и в консоли напишет `ошибка: error Internal Server Booboo{"message":"ERROR","code":1337}`